# Lock and edit feature for all user including Admin

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, workflow

An Item if 'Lock and Edit' then creates a new version if not an admin.
As a admin When I select lock from Experience Editor Ribbon and edit the Item which is published once and save then new version is not created.
Is there a way to create new version everytime an item is edited in Experience editor mode irrespective of Admin role or not

Comment: This behavior is expected and by design. Consider creating a new account with lower privileges.

Comment: As Michael said, the admin account role bypasses a  lot of checks and verifications. This logic is hardcoded in the code and you cannot bypass it. Do not use Admin accounts for anyone other that developers, and don't use them for content entry.